# PHP email interception not sending email with attachments

Tags: php, apache, email, interception

I have set email interception on my server.

following is my email forwarder set on server

testemail@my.server.com,"/home/server/php_pipe_mail.php"

following is my code for php_pipe_mail.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php 

require_once('mimeDecode.php');
include('sql-connect.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


ob_start();


$raw_email = '';



if (!$stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "R"))
{
    echo "ERROR: UNABLE TO OPEN php://stdin \n";
}

// ABLE TO READ THE MAIL
else
{
    while (!feof($stdin))
    {
        $raw_email .= fread($stdin, 4096);
    }
    fclose($stdin);
}



$raw_email = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $raw_email);


var_dump($raw_email);


$buf = ob_get_contents();

$params['include_bodies'] = true;
$params['decode_bodies'] = true;
$params['decode_headers'] = true;
$params['input'] = $buf;
$params['crlf'] = "\r\n"; 

//Creating temp file on server 
$myFile = "amail.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $buf);
fclose($fh);


//Generating mail structure in object format
$structure = Mail_mimeDecode::decode($params); 
$attachment = array();

$mail_date= date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($structure->headers['date']) );
$from = $structure->headers['from'];
$to = $structure->headers['to'];
$subject = htmlentities($structure->headers['subject'],ENT_QUOTES);
if($structure->ctype_primary == "multipart")
{
    $body_text = $structure->parts[0]->parts[0]->body;
$body_html = $structure->parts[0]->parts[1]->body;

$x = 0;
//fetch attachment
foreach ($structure->parts as $part) {
    // only save if an attachment
    if (isset($part->disposition) and ($part->disposition=='attachment')) {
        $attachment[$x]["filename"] = $part->d_parameters['filename'];
        $attachment[$x]["content_type"] = $part->ctype_primary . "/" .          $part->ctype_secondary;
        $attachment[$x]["body"] = addslashes($part->body);
        $x++;
    }
}
}
else 
{
$body_text = $structure->parts[0]->body;
$body_html = $structure->parts[1]->body;
}


$qry1 = "insert into mail_buffer(mail_date,mail_from,     mail_to,mail_subject,mail_text_body,mail_html_body) Values('". $mail_date ."','".$from."','".$to."','".$subject."','".$body_text."','".$body_html."')";

mysql_query($qry1) or die(mysql_error($con));

$last_id = mysql_insert_id();

if(count($attachment) > 0)
{
for($i=0; $i < count($attachment); $i++)
{
    $qry = "insert into mail_attachment(email_id,content_type, file_name,body) Values('". $last_id ."','".$attachment[$i]['content_type']."','".$attachment[$i]['filename']."','".$attachment[$i]['body']."')";
    mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error($con));
}
}



mysql_close($con);

ob_end_clean();

?>
```

Now above script works perfectly fine.

I am able to fetch message header, body and attachments and can store them in database without any problems.

When email without attachments come everything works fine and email is delivered to email address I am intercepting.

But following is not working.

When email with attachments comes than email content is being stored in database but email is not delivering to email address I am intercepting and I am getting following error message in bounce back email.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

pipe to |/home/server/php_pipe_mail.php
generated by testemail@my.server.com

Can anyone help me regarding the matter.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Denis, can you give me some idea about how can it help me resolving my problem. is that anything wrong in code?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that, when an attachment is present, your script is echoing something? I have had problems piping emails before, and seen failure messages returned to senders, and they have been due to the piping script producing some kind of output. Maybe your `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is allowing the script to produce an output - try `error_reporting(0);`